# Time dependent PDE in polar coordinate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, polar-coordinates, dirac-delta, greens-function

Can anybody help me with this time-dependent PDE in polar coordinate:

$$u_t=k\left(u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta \theta}\right)$$

with Boundary condition:
$$u(r,\theta, 0)=\frac{1}{\pi R}\delta(r-R),\ \ \ a<r<b$$
$$u(a,\theta,t)=0, \ \ \ t>=0$$
$$u_r(b,\theta,t)=0, \ \ \ t>=0$$
$$u_\theta(r,0,t)=0, \ \ \ t>=0$$
$$u_\theta(r,\pi,t)=0, \ \ \ t>=0$$

I eliminated the time dependence using Laplace transform, then I couldn't find a general solution to separate $\theta$ and $r$.

After Laplace transformation:
$$\hat{u}_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}\hat{u}_r+\frac{1}{r^2}\hat{u}_{\theta \theta}-ks\hat{u}=-\frac{k}{\pi R}\delta(r-R)$$ where $\hat{u}{(r,s, \theta)}=\int^{\infty}_0u(r,\theta,t)e^{-st}dt$

Comment: Could you add the equation after applying the Laplace Transform?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the post

Comment: This is just the heat equation $u_t=ku_{xx}$ in polar coordinates. Have you tried the usual separation of variables and Fourier series solution?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't separate the variables with a delta function on the rhs. My mathematics is awful...Can you give me some hits?